# Ajustar fuente de texto de un pdfFormField para que no supere el tamaño del campo, iText Java

Tags: java, formularios, fuentes, itext

Estoy trabajando con iText 7.2.5 en java
Tengo una plantilla de un pdf que tiene formularios, estoy rellenandolos automaticamente pero necesito saber cuando el texto supera la capacidad de el campo de texto para poder reducir el tamaño de la fuente.

[image: Ejemplo]

En la imagen se puede ver un ejemplo de cuando pones mucho texto deja de ser visible la totalidad y aparece ese simbolo de +

Quiero saber como puedo comprobar si se ha sobrepasado el limite de campo y ajustar el tamaño de la fuente en consecuencia, evidentemente habra un limite donde la fuente ya no sera legible pero, el objetivo es que el sistema sea flexible dentro de un rango de tamaños de fuente

A continuacion el codigo de como asigno el valor al campo:

```
PdfFormField campoPDF = formulario.getFormFields().get("PESO");
        
campoPDF.setValue("asdfghjklasdfghjk");
```

Answer (score 0):

si quieres calcular el espacio que te va a ocupar un texto, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
String texto = "Hola";
Font font = new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14 );
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = canvas.getFontMetrics( font );
int ancho = fm.stringWidth( texto );
```